# SQL 2008 and Backup Exec 12

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, backupexec

First time here so please go easy on me! We've read that Backup Exec 12 and MS SQL 2008 don't really work well (if at all) together and was wondering if anyone had any issues with set up on the same box?

Is an upgrade to 12.5 free?

We also had a sales guy in recently who was dissing Backup Exec and recommending CommVault...

Cheers!

John

**Turns out installing SQL 2008 has broken the Backup Exec DB on the SQL 2005 Express! I don't think you can even have these 2 installed on the same box. :-(**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symantec don't support SQL Server 2008 with thee Backup Exec 12 Remote Agent. As far as I am aware BackupExec will require it's own instance of SQL 2005 as its backing store, you could use the free version that comes with BackupExec to install and run BackupExec 12 and SQL 2008 on the same box. You would have to maintain both SQL 2005 and SQL 2008 with regards to updates.

The upgrade to 12.5 is only free if you have a maintancce agreement (which costs about 10% of the initial purchace price a year). However an upgrade is avaialble if you don't have maintance, remember you will have to upgrade the media server and the remote agents if you are backing up to/from more than one server.

Comment: Most helpful answer thanks

John

Answer (score 1):

I would never have Backup Exec backing up direct from the SQL Server, but instead use SQL Maintenance Plans to create the backup files and then use Backup Exec to backup those files just like any other files... saves the cost of a SQL Agent.

Comment: True, but you have to weigh up the cost of a £300 SQL Agent versus how much it'd cost the business to be down for another hour or so while you try and retrieve last nights SQL Backup files from tape, then reimport those in to your SQL Server. Having the SQL Agent eliminates a step allowing for faster restore times, which might be £300 well spent.

Comment: steveburkett, valid point. I am in the habit of having my files stored on multiple hard disks as well as backup drives (external hard disks), so the (overall) restore times are usually pretty minimal. The cost of hard drives now make this a very economical solution... I do have Backup Exec performing backups, but my first port of call would be the hard disk (local) backup files if available.

Answer (score 0):

Handy hint, not sure if they sorted this out with version 12+, but with version 11 atleast we always tried to use a seperate install of SQL 2005 Express for our Backup Exec's as whenever you ran an update/hotfix on the setup, the installer routine would shut down your SQL Server service without any warning, do the hotfix, then restart the SQL Server service. Nice if you've installed the BE database on your production SQL server.

REALLY badly thought out and something I repeatedly voiced concern about but to no avail. We soon got in the habit of installing it to its own little SQL 2005 Express DB.

Might save some pain.

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade is free (if you have maintenance) but since it's not working now is the perfect time to evaluate other products.  Commvault is  great product, suprisingly (at least for me) Microsoft's system center data protection manager is pretty good too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to try other products, i can recommend a cheap and quick backup software from Red-Gate. Red-gate Backup may use compression to reduce disk size. We used Backup Exec before, but Red-gate backup was like 10 times faster.

/Håkan Winther